# What's the point of having static nodes when IP addresses keep changing?

Tags: private-blockchain, nodes, connections, enode

In the `<datadir>/static-nodes.json` file, we can mention the enode URI of a node that we want to re-connect to, in case of a connection failure. Assume `A` is a static node which has been rebooted. Now, it has a different IP address to the one stored in `static-nodes.json` file. Since IP address is a part of the enode URI, how do other nodes find out the new IP address of `A` and re-connect to it (in a private blockchain network). Is the `static-nodes.json` file updated every time this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only write nodes with a static IP in `<datadir>/static-nodes.json`.

Incidentally, the enode is a way for the client to ensure it does not loop back to itself.